# ¿se pueden hacer preguntas retóricas enfocadas a la teoría de un tema?

Tags: discusión

Actualmente me gustaría saber si puedo hacer preguntas de la siguiente forma:

*¿Es necesario relacionar mi tabla de Logs o Bitacora de BD con todas las tablas de mi app?.
Soy muy nuevo en esto de la programación y me surgió esta duda ya que estoy desarrollando una app independiente y como quiero que tenga una historial de todas las acciones de mi app, quería saber si era necesaria tener una tabla exclusiva para los logs y de ser así si debo relacionarla con todas las demás de mi app.*

Toda la parte de arriba es mi pregunta y quisiera saber sin son validas realizarlas de esta forma, no busco que se me responda aquí y solo saber si la puedo publicar en el foro principal y de no poder hacerlo, si hay alguna forma de modificarla para que sea aceptable.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres cuando dices "pregunta retórica"? Una pregunta retórica es una pregunta para la que no esperas respuesta ya que es más una afirmación pero hecha en forma de pregunta. No creo que te refieras a eso porque supongo que esperas respuestas para tu duda.

Comment: Sería muy bueno responder a esta pregunta comenzando con un _¿deberíamos hacer preguntas retóricas al contestar?..._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que tu pregunta, caeria en lo que se llama basada en opiniones. No es facil armar la estructura de una base de datos, un sistema de logueo, o como se llame.

Puede que haya diferentes puntos de vista sobre como armar eso, dependiendo la tecnologia que uses, que tengas a mano, el ambiente de deploy, las capacidades tecnicas de tus servidores.

No creo que exista una respuesta correcta a esa pregunta, todas darian a debate.

La forma de replantear la pregunta seria con un escenario mucho mas directo, con referencias de hard, tecnologias y todas las cosas relevantes del caso. Y sin embargo, tengo mis dudas de que la respuesta sea unica.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es redactar las preguntas de forma directa, completa, pero sin adornos retóricos.

El uso de preguntas retóricas en preguntas sobre los temas que se pueden tratar en este sitio hace las preguntas mas largas de lo necesario, se corre el riesgo de que sea mal interpretada y que las preguntas parezcan basadas en opiniones.

El caso de la pregunta mostrada parece basada en opiniones e incompleta pues no se indica lo buscado/investigado sobre el tema.